# Import Django model class in Scrapy project

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a django project and a scrapy project

and I want to import django model from to scrapy project.

This is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/venv/dict')
from dmmactress.models import EnActress

class JpnNameSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = jp_name
allowed_domains = ['enjoyjapan.co.kr']
rx = EnActress.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
rxs = rx.reverse()
start_urls = ['http://enjoyjapan.co.kr/how_to_read_japanese_name.php?keyword=%s' % jp for jp in rxs]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response('//*[@id="contents"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]'):
        item = JapanessItem()
        item['koname'] = sel.xpath('div[4]/div[1]()/text()').extract()
        item['jpname'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/div[1]()/text()').extract()
        yield item

    next_page = response.css('#contents > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if naxt_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, self.parse)
```

and I got error when I ran spider

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configure.
```

-- Can someone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Django uses its settings.py and manage.py to do all kinds of magic to provide the glue between your model and the database. If you're just importing your model file you're gonna have a bad time. Can you sit the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [initialize Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#initialization-process)  before using models outside the context of Django apps:

```
import django 
django.setup()
```